# Changing UIImageView picture which name stored in a string

Tags: ios7, uiimageview

Hi there i have image views in my application to change pictures in them. but their name like imageview1, imageview2, and so.. i create a string which like:

```
 `("imageview%i", number)`
```

so my string is imageview1 for example. and i need to change

```
 self."**mystring**".image = [uiimage ...]
```

I looked key-value coding but i couldn't get it exactly. i searched the forum and i can't get anything either. what could i do to resolve this. i think i must do an array with my uiimageviews inside of it. than compare their name with my string (i didn't know how can i get property names as nsstring). then return that image view. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that in runtime, either hack your way using selectors or use tags on your UIImageViews. They are not really good programming concepts, but they work. Examples:

```
-(void)usingSelectors{
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
        NSString* propName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageview%d", i];
        UIImageView* imageView = [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(propName)];
        [imageView setImage:/*your image*/];
    }
}

-(void)usingTags{
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
        UIImageView* imageView = [self.view viewWithTag:i];
        [imageView setImage:/*your image*/];
    }
}
```

If you want to do that in compile time you'll have to use preprocessor macros, but I don't think that's your case.

Comment: Yes I needed to do it in runtime because i had a minimap concept for an exact number of tiles and i just wanted to do show the character's location to user. As he venture through the map there will be some another items to show the user. i ain't got an idea to do that. i just remove or add pictures as user ventures.